# Overlay in Flutter freezes the Application

Tags: flutter, dart

I hope you are Safe.
 I have been trying to build a flutter app, that shows an overlay with suggestions of hashtags based on what user has typed. I have not worked on the suggestion part so Im just displaying random country names
I have Used this Medium  [Article](https://medium.com/saugo360/https-medium-com-saugo360-flutter-using-overlay-to-display-floating-widgets-2e6d0e8decb9)  to integrate overlay in my Project.
**Here is my only flutter file.**

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String sugg;
  bool isHashTag;

  OverlayEntry _overlayEntry;
  final TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController();

   OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry() {

    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
    var size = renderBox.size;
    var offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

    return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => Positioned(
        left: offset.dx,
        top: offset.dy + size.height + 5.0,
        width: size.width,
        child: Material(
          elevation: 4.0,
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                title: Text('Syria'),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text('Lebanon'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("test"),
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  autocorrect: false,
                  controller: myController,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    val.split("");
                    if (val[val.length - 2] == " " &&
                        val[val.length - 1] == "#") {
                      isHashTag = true;
                      
                    }
                    if (val[val.length - 1] == " ") {
                      this._overlayEntry.remove();
                      isHashTag = false;
                      print(sugg);
                      sugg = '';
                    }
                    if (isHashTag == true) {
                      sugg = sugg + val[val.length - 1];
                      this._overlayEntry = this._createOverlayEntry();
                      Overlay.of(context).insert(this._overlayEntry);
                    }
                  },
                ),
                FlatButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Submit"))
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm not getting the overlay even when the conditions are met, I would like to know how can this be fixed.Thank you!